# Cache issues with images not showing up

Tags: images, cache

Images are there, but they don't always show up.

Could this be a cache problem? Or Timbthumb?

Here is an example: http://designportugal.net/servicos/design/ 
And another: http://designportugal.net/portfolio/#all/3/list

I  sometimes also have trouble getting into WP dashboard, it gives a warning php error, but when I refresh, it goes away and I get inside fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I visit your first link and look at the response, I get a `500 Internal Server Error` when trying to get the following resource: `http://designportugal.net/wp-content/themes/dt-nimble/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/drpedrocoelho.png&zc=1&w=30&h=30` so my guess is that your problem is with the `timthumb` plugin. Try disabling the plugin and see if your error goes away.

Comment: did you try to refresh? I can see it. Sometimes when you refresh a page it works - but that is annoying. It is possibly still connected to timthumb though? I cannot disable it though, it's in the theme itself probably (it's not in the plugins folder). How do I do that?

Comment: I don't know really, have never used the plugin myself. You should check your error logs and if possible set `WP_DEBUG` to true in your `wp-config.php` file in order to isolate the problem. Checkout this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Comment: Here's a link that is related to this problem: http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/tim-thumb-problem/32860

Comment: Thanks Krister, I'll edit the wp-config and see what's up.

Comment: I CHMODed the timthumb's cache folder from 755 to 777 and it's working. Fingers crossed it keeps that way. If timthumb is not in the plugins folder, then it's inside the WP theme you're using - that was my case. I did not know where the cache folder was but I opened timthumb-config.php and in there there was the path to it (in wp-content/uploads/themes)